# How to display Clojure version in REPL?

Tags: clojure, version

Such as:

```
(println clojure-version)
```

?

Answer (score 95):

Even shorter :

```
user> (clojure-version)
"1.2.0-beta1"
user>
```

Oops, I have to upgrade...

Answer (score 31):

Very close.

```
user> (println *clojure-version*)
{:major 1, :minor 2, :incremental 0, :qualifier }
nil
```

Most builtin "global" variables like this have Common Lisp-style asterisk "earmuffs".

Comment: You can also just type *clojure-version* and the REPL will print the toString value. Fancy, that!

Answer (score 23):

Just typing `*clojure-version*` will do the trick.

```
*clojure-version*
=> {:major 1, :minor 3, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extra repl examples

```
user=> (clojure-version)
"1.10.1"

user=> (println (clojure-version))
1.10.1
nil

user=> (print (clojure-version))
1.10.1nil
```

Use from clj

```
$ clj -M -e "(clojure-version)"
"1.10.1"

$ clj -M -e "(print (clojure-version))"
1.10.1

$ clj -M -e "*clojure-version*"
{:major 1, :minor 10, :incremental 1, :qualifier nil}
```

Answer (score 1):

clojure -M -e '(println "Java" (System/getProperty "java.version") "Clojure" (clojure-version))'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).